# Verification: If $x_n \rightarrow 5$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $x_n^2 \rightarrow 25$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Ignoring the fact that there is a much simpler proof using product of limits, is this $\epsilon$ proof solid for the question in the title?

---

Since $x_n \rightarrow 5$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then since $\frac{\epsilon}{11} > 0, \exists N_1$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N_1$ we have $|x_n -5| < \frac{\epsilon}{11}$. Likewise, since $\epsilon = 1 >0, \exists N_2$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N_2$ we have $|x_n -5| < 1 \implies x_n < 6$.

Then let $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ then $\forall n \geq N$ we get:

$|x_n^2 - 25| = |x_n -5||x_n + 5| < 11|x_n - 5| < \frac{11\epsilon}{11} = \epsilon 
 $

Comment: Seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to assert not only that $x_n<6$ but also that $x_n>-4$ in order to claim that $|x_n+5|<11$. But this is a detail many teachers wouldn't worry about.